# Generating 1sec Time Delay using Timer on Arduino Uno with ATmega328P (C Language)

Tags: timer, delay, microcontroller, avr, arduino-uno

**Hardware** : Arduino Uno with ATmega328P

**Software** : Atmel Studio 6.2.1153, Arduino 1.0.6

**Calculating the cycles needed for 1s**

- **Clock Frequency of ATmega328P**            = 16M Hz
- **Clock Frequency with Prescaler CLK/1024**  = 16M / 1024    = 15625 Hz
- **Clock Period with Prescaler CLK/1024** = (15625)^-1    = 6.4*10^-5s
- **Cycles of 1s**                         = 1 / 6.4*10^-5 = 15625 cycles
- **Cycle needed for 1s**                      = 15625 - 1     = 15624 cycles  = 0x3D08

**My Codes**

```
OCR1AH = 0x3D;                      //Load higher byte of 15624 into output compare register
OCR1AL = 0x08;                      //Load lower byte of 15624 into output compare register
TCCR1A = 0b00000000;
TCCR1B = 0b00001101;                //Turn on CTC mode and prescaler of CLK/1024 
while((TIFR1 & (1<<OCF1A)) == 0);   //If OCF1A is set (TCNT1 = OCR1A), break 
TCCR1A = 0;
TCCR1B = 0;                         //Stop the timer
TIFR1 &= ~(1<<OCF1A);               //Clear OCF1A for the next time delay
```

When I click "Start Debugging and Break" and "step over" the above codes as a function. It always show me "running" without a stop. Why? How to solve it?

---

***Thank you for your help.***

Comment: https://github.com/dwelch67/avr_samples should have some second or multi-second led blinkers...

Comment: One problem is that you are not clearing the `OCF1A` flag on the last line. It should be `TIFR1 = 1<<OCF1A;`.

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration looks OK.

When You pause execution of Your code in debugger, peripherals (independent of CPU) are not stopped. Some architectures/microcontrollers have additional hardware registers to stop peripherals (such a DMA or timers) when execution of code is stopped by debugger. Anyway, AVR does not.

If You are running Your code in simulation, You should be able to see all registers set by instructions, step-by-step. I advise You to turn off code optimizations for debugging purposes.

For debugging code in hardware (in case of AVR architecture) you need additional debugger. Debugging provided by Arduino use only software running over Your code in MPU and in some cases You cant rely on it.

Anyway, your code looks right. Only mistake: write logic 1 to TIFR1 to clear bit.

You should run Your code in loop to check if timer is working:

```
OCR1AH = 0x3D;                      //Load higher byte of 15624 into output compare register
OCR1AL = 0x08;                      //Load lower byte of 15624 into output compare register
TCCR1A = 0b00000000;
TCCR1B = 0b00001101;                //Turn on CTC mode and prescaler of CLK/1024 
while(1)
{
    while((TIFR1 & (1<<OCF1A)) == 0);   //If OCF1A is set (TCNT1 = OCR1A), break 
    //Blink LED here
    TIFR1 = (1<<OCF1A);               //Writing logic 1 to that register clears it
}
```

Of course if You dont want to run code in loop, just remove it. That code is just for testing purposes.

**Edit:**

Take look at Atmega328 datasheet: http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8161.pdf, pages 139-140, TIFR1 register, bit 1 – OCF1A:

> OCF1A is cleared by hardware when executing the corresponding interrupt. OCF1A can also be cleared by writing a logic one to that bit.

Some bits hardware registers (usually, which only can be cleared by user, never set by user) can be cleared by writing 1. Hardware connected with register **set 0** to bit value when you **write 1** to it. Writing 0 is ignored and not affect register/bit value. That prevents from setting bit from software, when bit may be set only with hardware (that case - timer). Think about it - there is no sense setting output compare register from code. Other actions (reading value, clearing bit) have sense and are allowed.

There are also some registers which can only be written, and not read (ie read always return same value).

When working with hardware registers remember to always check in datasheet how to set/clear bits.

Comment: Why I have to set OCF1A to 1 instead of 0 for clearing the bit? Can you explain more about it? Thanks.

Comment: `TIFR1 |= (1<<OCF1A);` clears all the flags, not just `OCF1A`. It should be `TIFR1 = (1<<OCF1A);`.

Comment: @UncleO : thank You - fixed code and add explanation for clearing bits.